# UPDATE with a JOIN & GROUP

Tags: mysql

I want to update all user records with the number of emails associated to that user. So I have

| userid | name | emailcount |

and

| userid | emaildata

I am trying to make a single UPDATE query which which will fill the emailcount with the number of emails that user has.

I have tried using a single UPDATE but can't make it work; do I need to use a subquery somehow to do this?

Comment: Why not derive emailcount from the table that contains emaildata? This way you don't have to worry about emailcount and rows in the table that includes emaildata being synchronized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this action I suggest this query, but it is not tested on MySQL, I don't have the access at this moment. I hope that it is correct if not please others can correct me

```
UPDATE user SET emailcount = (SELECT count(*) FROM emaildata WHERE emaildata.userid  user.userid)
```

Comment: Just so I understand this correctly, I presume mySQL will internally run a query for each row of the user table to get that count?

Comment: @Christopher Yes, it is slow but it works. I suppose that you don't want to execute it too often

Answer (score 2):

As Elliot suggests, you can drop the column `emailcount` and generate the value dynamically with a query like this:

```
select userid, name, coalesce(ec.count, 0) as emailcount
from User u
left outer join (
    select userid, count(*) as count
    from Email
    group by userid
) ec on u.userid = ec.userid
```

Comment: The question is a large simplification of a much more complicated use case in reality; it's just this is the bit i need to work out.

Comment: I am not sure if this is wise and necessary because we don't know amount of data in the database and this query can be really slow. I can imagine that he has slow application with your structure and he are optimizing it with making redundant data which will be managed by application in the future but now he has to create them - I hope that I explained it clearly

Comment: In this case it is fine as this is a query that only needs to be run every month; and not against a huge database. It's for reporting usage really (best way of explaining it)

Comment: I'd be interested to know if there was a way to do it in a single query - i would think using a temporary table would be the best way to do it in say 2 queries.